# c# linq группировка по диапазону с условием

Tags: c#, list, linq, order-by

Имеется список со значениями координат:

```
List<(int,int)> coord = new List<(int,int)>() {(554,79),(553,79),(554,79), (23,600),(22,600),(22,600)};
```

Необходимо сгруппировать диапазон по item1

> 554,553,554

и

> 23,22,22

Группировку делаю так:

```
 List<(int,int)> g_coord = coord.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

Как мне захватить в группировку рядом стоящие числа (554 и 553, 22 и 23)
Т.е там где координата отличается всего на 1?

Пока сделал такой костыль:

```
       List<(int, int)> coords = new List<(int, int)>() {
        (553,126),
        (554,126),
        (554,127),
        (553,126),
        (41,126),
        (40,126),
        (45,120),
        (44,120),
        (46,120),
        (553,127),
        (1001,44),
        (1002,45),
        };

        List<(int, int)> newcoords = new List<(int, int)>();
// Удалить дубликаты
        coords = coords.GroupBy(x => x.Item1).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
// перебор списка
        for (var j = 0; j < coords.Count(); j++)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(coords[j].Item1 + "x" + coords[j].Item2);
            for (var i = 0; i < coords.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(coords[j].Item1+ "==" +coords[i].Item1);
                if (Math.Abs(coords[j].Item1 - coords[i].Item1)==1) { 
                    coords.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            newcoords.Add(coords[j]);

        }
```

Comment: А что должно быть в результате, если есть точки 555, 556, 557, 558? Эти четыре точки будут в одной группе или нет?

Comment: А зачем с linq'ом шаманить? Пробежался бы просто циклом и раскидал по группам.

Comment: +1 к вопросу @AndreiKhotko. Лучше вообще взять вырожденный случай: координаты  (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) ... до (999,999) по диагонали. Каков ожидаемый результат? Если на выходе должна быть одна группа, то алгоритм один; если есть ограничение на максимальное расстояние внутри группы, то совсем другой.

Comment: Да возможно не корректор я вопрос задал. Нужно объединить рядом стоящие точки в одну. т.е x = 554, х=553,  x = 554. Погрешность у них в 1 пиксель. Объединить их в наибольшее значение 554.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

1. Узнаете количество цифр в каждом числе(ведь 50 и 500 должны попасть в разные группировки)
2. Узнаете первую цифру каждого числа( в 50 и 500 это будет 5)
3. Группируете по первому числу и по количеству цифр в числе( т е {5, 2} и {5,3} будет две группировки.

*пример кода*

```
        var integs = new[] { 501, 551, 523, 20, 40 };

        var res = integs
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Count = (int)Math.Log10(x) + 1,
                Value = x
            })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                First = x.Value / (int)Math.Pow(10, x.Count - 1),
                Count = x.Count,
                Value = x.Value
            })
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.First, x.Count })
            .ToArray();
```

Вывод:

```
{{5,3} => 501, 551, 523}
{{2,2} => 20}
{{4,2} => 40}
```

Comment: У 499 и 500, или 99 и 100, нет ничего общего?

Comment: Посмотрите на мой костыль. Он работает почти правильно. Но что то не то. )